# Script to delete a command and associated curly braces from source in TeXShop?

Tags: texshop, scripts

When I'm editing the source in TeXShop, I often find that I want to remove emphasis from a word or phrase. But deleting the `\emph` from the beginning of the word and the `{}` surrounding it is a bit more annoying than I would like it to be.

I suppose what I'm looking for is a script that I can execute at the start of a command (like `\emph`) that will scan left-to-right and delete everything except for the text between the curly braces (i.e., that will delete the "\emph", the "{", and the "}")

Something that would take me from

```
This is \emph{emphasized} text
```

to

```
This is emphasized text
```

In the code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a TeX solution, but you can use a regular expression, for example in vim:

```
:%s/\\emph{\([^}]*\)}/\1/g
```

Caveats: doesn't remove inner `\emph`'s (`\emph{foo \emph{bar} baz}`), nor if the `\emph` spans multiple lines. (Feel free to comment for improvements!)

Comment: After a bit of googling, it seems that applescript doesn't support regular expressions (and I think TeXShop only supports applescripts though I really can't be sure, all of this stuff is VERY new for me).

Is there a way to modify this into something applescript compatible that you know of?

The standard fix seems to be to use shell commands (cf. http://erik.arvedson.se/2009/08/using-regular-expressions-in.html)

Is this something you could help with?

Comment: @Dennis: Yes, you can use regular expressions with for example the command line utility `sed`, where the above expression would be the same except the first `%`. So, for example: `sed 's/\\emph{\([^}]*\)}/\1/g' name-of-your-file.tex` which would output the input after `sed` has made its changes (so you could forward the output with `sed '....' file.tex > file_after_sed.tex` for example). The same caveats apply, though.

Comment: Doesn't work with nested commands in general.

Answer (score 3):

If the same modifications must be made for **all** the `\emph` command in large documents or some big parts, I suggest you do not touch the \emph command at all, but redefine the command (in the preamble or in the body document). The main advantage is that you can easily switch between styles without touch each word emphasized. The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
% Normal behaviour  
normal text \emph{emphasis text} \par
% Emphasis out
\renewcommand{\emph}[1]{#1}
normal text \emph{emphasis text} \par
% Emphasis become bold text
\renewcommand{\emph}[1]{\textbf{#1}} 
normal text \emph{emphasis text} \par
% Emphasis become underlined text
\renewcommand{\emph}[1]{\underline{#1}}
normal text \emph{emphasis text} \par
\end{document}
```

[image: emph]

Comment: This is very useful (hence the upvote) but not quite what I was looking for.

I'm looking more for a way to speed up the editing process by removing a single unwanted emphasis from a word or phrase. I suppose what I'm looking for is something like a macro that I can execute at the start of a command (like `\emph`) that will scan left-to-right and delete everything except for the text between the curly braces (i.e., that will delete the "\emph", the "{", and the "}").

Comment: Are you looking for a text editor with the ability to record and execute macros (as Nedit for Linux and Notepad++ in Windows) or a LaTeX macro? For the first see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors

Comment: Sorry, my original question was a bit confused. It seems that a script might be the fix for me.

Morsbug's answer seems to have the solution but I can't be sure until I figure out how to implement it as an applescript.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

% \disable takes two arguments and only uses the second
\makeatletter
\let\disable\@secondoftwo
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is \emph{emphasized} text

This is \disable\emph{emphasized} text

\end{document}
```

Comment: That certainly achieves the effect. What I was really looking for was a macro or script or something that would actually remove the "\emph", the "{", and the "}" from my source.

Something that would take me from

`This is \emph{emphasized} text`

to

`This is emphasized text`

In the code itself.

I might be asking for something very difficult or impossible, though.

At any rate, with a key binding your suggestion would be just about as effective and have wider applicability.

Do you understand my question, though?

I apologize for asking such an unclear question.

Comment: I guess it should be doable to write a script that removes all `\emph`'s (including the braces) from the source but that's a task for someone else than me.